# How do I get a variable amount of input from cin?

Tags: c++

I've been working on a calculator and I am very close to getting it working, but I need to find a way to have the amount of numbers and operators that the user puts in to be up to the user. This is a simpler test version of what I have so far that I need to apply this to. I left out a few things but this is the exact part of the code I need to apply it to. The user should be able to input any amount of numbers and operands as long as it is under 20 of each. I don't want to stick to a rigid form of input, like `cin >> numIn[n]; cin >> operator1[n]`, because then you would HAVE to end with an operator, for example.

```
#include <iostream>

float numIn[20];
char operator1[20];

int main(){
int n = 0;
while (n < 20){
std::cin >> numIn[n] >> operator1[n];
switch (operator1[n]){
case '+':
 std::cout << numIn[n] + numIn[n];
 break;
default:
 std::cout << "does not work";
}
}
}
```

I edited this question to be more focused and clear. I added the part of the text above about how I need to have a 'fluid' way of input. If this doesn't make it more clear I don't know what does.

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::getline`?

Comment: You can use an `std::string` instead of a fixed-capacity `char` array.

Comment: you could use `std::cin >> numIn[n];
std::cin >> operator1[n];`

Comment: When I made my calculator, I used input of '=' as an indicator to terminate the while(true) loop I used to get input. In your case, if operator entered  is '=', terminate

Comment: if you want to read to seperate floats/chars and need access to all of them just use a `std::vector<float>` and `std::vector<char>` which allows you to do `float floatVal; std::cin >>floatVal; numInt.push_back(floatVal);` to add a new float to the vector.

Comment: @fabian thanks, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @debanshudas I am doing the same thing, this is just some test code that is much smaller than the whole project

Comment: Before implementing an interface, it helps to define the interface. *How* would the user indicate the amount of numbers and operators? Does the user have to count them in advance? Some special input to indicate "I'm done"? Just keep going (showing intermediate results) until the program is forcibly killed? *(If you refine your question enough, you might find you can ask it without needing to mention that you are working on a calculator. Think abstractly and focus on a specific task.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getline` to get a whole line of input from the user.
Then use that string to construct a `stringstream`, which you can use your `>>` on to extract the numbers and single-char operators.  But now you get an error when you try to read past the end of the original string.  It knows you are done, because it has the complete input committed before it started to read, unlike an always-open terminal where the user could always type more.

Answer (score 0):

use `std::cin >> numIn[n]` and `std::cin >> operator1 [n]`

as @Ivan suggested in the replies

Comment: I've tried that. I don't especially know why but it didn't work.

Comment: could u post the error and the program you executed here ?

Comment: I just mean it yielded similar/the same results. Not really an error, just not a solution. Thanks a lot for your contribution, though.